# EACCES Error with Bower install?

Tags: terminal, bower, steroids

I've read a few answers on StackOverflow & some other sites but none seem to fix the issue I'm having.

I'm installing AppGyver Add-ons, via terminal. Getting the following error:

```
BradMacBookPro:SparksInSpain breadadams$ bower install https://##MY-DOWNLOAD-CODE##@addons.appgyver.com/steroids-addons.js?version=3.1.0 --save
bower not-cached    https://##MY-DOWNLOAD-CODE##@addons.appgyver.com/steroids-addons.js?version=3.1.0#*
bower resolve       https://##MY-DOWNLOAD-CODE##@addons.appgyver.com/steroids-addons.js?version=3.1.0#*
bower download      https://##MY-DOWNLOAD-CODE##@addons.appgyver.com/steroids-addons.js?version=3.1.0
bower EACCES        EACCES, mkdir '/Users/breadadams/.cache/bower/packages/7480e059b318750565b4b25c2556c9c4'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/breadadams/.cache/bower/packages/7480e059b318750565b4b25c2556c9c4'

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:74:17)
    at Logger.updateNotifier.packageName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:109:18)
    at Logger.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/install.js:27:16
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.2.8
Node version: 0.10.25
OS: Darwin 13.1.0 x64
```

I'm not sudo, I've tried --allow-root, cleaned the bower cache, always get the same error on install. Some local permission problem?

Comment: ##MY-DOWNLOAD-CODE## is my download code I've hidden btw, just a heads up that's not the problem :)

Comment: sudo chown -R breadadams /Users/breadadams/.cache/bower/packages/7480e059b318750565b4b25c2556c9c4'

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I had a similar issue that I couldn't resolve using these suggestions. I was successful when I ran Bower with root privileges, like so:

```
sudo bower install --allow-root
```

Comment: If this worked, then you have a permissions issue. Using the chown command as others have specified below will actually fix the error.

You can navigate to /Users/<username>/.config/configstore and use "ls -l" to check ownership. If any of those files are owned by root, that is likely what is causing the issue. This is where you use "sudo chown -R .config/" (assuming you're in the same directory as the .config dir) to change the user ownership. Check similarly on the ~/.cache directory

Comment: After that command I suggest (as suggested below) to run:
`$ sudo chown YOUUSERNAME:staff ~/.config/configstore/bower-github.json ~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-bower.json`

Comment: I tried the first comment and my user owns the file and the group is staff. How do I fix this issue for the future?

Comment: Changing the permissions as stated below is the proper fix for this I think.

Answer (score 43):

Change the ownership for the .config and cache directory

```
sudo chown -R username:username ~/.config
```

and

```
sudo chown -R username:username ~/.cache
```

Comment: I used yours but modified.

sudo chown -R username ~/.config
sudo chown -R username ~/.cache    

without the extra ":username"

and mine worked. What is the purpose of the :username?

Comment: This is a good solution. Thanks. You can also use the user alias: sudo chown -R $USER  ~/.config AND sudo chown -R $USER  ~/.cache.

Comment: @TylerDavis it is specified like username:usergroup   where usergroup may have many users. but by default there is not usergroup is created hence your command worked.

Comment: I had inadvertently installed bower and npm as root, and have not been able to run them without sudo/--allow-root for a long, long time.  This fixed it for me, thank you very much.

Comment: @Tyler Davis you have saved my day!

Answer (score 35):

I noticed you tried this from a MacBook Pro.

You could try this:

- go to the finder
- under menu go Go To Folder type this: `~/.cache/bower`
- delete its content and try again.

> Also as **@Edwin** suggested you may try:
>
> The command `bower cache clean` which will have the same effect irrespective of OS.

Comment: Thanks, I was facing a similar problem while using Ember-CLI, where the installation stopped because bower failure to rename tmp directories. Did as you suggested, and everything worked fine. Thanks again :)

Comment: Alternatively the command `bower cache clean` will have the same effect irrespective of OS.

Comment: `bower cache clean` was still throwing errors, had to `cd` to the cache folder and delete manually.

Comment: Same problem as Christopher, removing the directory was required for me. Strange as `bower cache clean` has worked for me in the past, but I've since updated a lot so maybe bower has changed in that respect.

Answer (score 10):

Im not sure what happened with my project but in order to fix the issues with bower  I had to run the following.

```
sudo npm install -g bower

sudo bower cache clean --allow-root 

rm -Rf bower_components

sudo bower install --allow-root
```

Im still not really sure what went wrong but after those commands i was up and running

Comment: I have tried everything above and only this fixed for me! Much appreciated! 
P.S. Why does this happen? My working project just broke suddenly. I have not made any changes ...

Answer (score 6):

1) run

```
$groups
```

to get the name of your group

2) then run

```
$sudo chown -R {user}:{group} ~/.config 
$sudo chown -R {user}:{group} ~/.cache
```

where {user} - is username and {group} - is group name

Comment: May be of help running also `$sudo chown -R {user}:{group} ~/.cache`.

Comment: how it is different to what I wrote?

Comment: Copy paste issue. I didn't mean .cache, I meant `~/.npm`

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same thing and noticed that the bower_components folder was owned by the root user. I changed ownership to my user and everything worked without having to run bower as root.

```
sudo chown -R $USER bower_components
```

Answer (score 3):

Like everyone says, bower and npm shouldn't be run with sudo.
This corrected the problem for me on my OSX machine.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Now you should be able to run:

```
npm install
npm start
```

and even

```
bower install
```

without having to use sudo.

*note npm start usually calls bower install

Comment: May be of help running also `$sudo chown -R {user}:{group} ~/.cache`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but nothing above worked for me. If you recently updated Xcode and don't recognize, don't forget to agree the terms and install the command line tools!

`xcode-select --install`