# Error: EACCES: permission denied doing bower install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

I do `bower install css-circle-menu`

and I got this error :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/james/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
```

Tried sudo bower install css-circle-menu, it doesn't work too. Also tried to install bower global again, got the same error.

Comment: Related: [nearly every other question using the search `"EACCES: permission denied" code:"throw"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22EACCES%3A+permission+denied%22+code%3A%22throw%22). Maybe there’s something useful for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EACCES Error with Bower install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257726/eacces-error-with-bower-install)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by insufficient user permissions. You can avoid the issue invoking a `sudo` command but I suggest you to try to fixing your `.config` folder permissions using:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Bower and NPM commands shouldn't be run with sudo.

Comment: Cheers.Was having recurring issues with bower installs. `sudo bower install --allow root` worked at first but then it started complaining also. Didn't really like the idea of `sudo`ing all the time either so this command did the trick.Now `bower install` simply works!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `sudo bower install css-circle-menu --allow-root`